# React: fading loaded image in, but not the cached one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

There are a lot of topics about animating the loaded image, but I haven't seen a great example of this in React yet. I came with this component myself:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function FadingImage({ src, ...props }) {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    return (
        <img
            src={src}
            onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
            className={!loaded ? 'loading' : ''}
            {...props}
        />
    );
};
```

```css
img {
    transition: opacity .25s;
}

.loading {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It works fine in the beginning, but then it's annoying that the same images get faded-in every single time. I'd like the cached images to appear instantly.

In vanilla JS it just works, because it's all done in the same render cycle. I'm not sure how it can be achieved in React.

Package suggestions are appreciated, but I'd also like to know how to do it for educational purpose.

Comment: try this package -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component

Comment: @AzeemAslam thanks, however my question remains.